# Handle iOS Version for MessageUI.Framework

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode4

I am using MessageUI.Framework in my app but the same could not be run on iOS 3.x. Is there any way in which we can check the OS version at compile time. I have tried few solutions([Soln_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862933/check-ios-version-at-runtime)  and  [Soln_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149813/programmatically-control-iphone-os-versions-to-enable-functions-for-both-os-3-x-a)) on web but they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution for the same

```
#ifdef _USE_OS_4_OR_LATER
   //code for iOS 4.0+
#elseif
   //code for the iOS < 4.0
#endif
```

This worked for me hope it does for all other as well.